# Docker - how to mount folder inside running container as volume to other running container?

Tags: linux, docker

As the question says, is it possible, once a container is already running, to create a mount inside it as a volume or otherwise, and to make that available to another container instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes that need to be mounted into other containers must be defined when you create the container image. i.e. in your docker file. Once a volume is defined in the image every time a container is created from the image the volume is created. You can then tell docker to mount the same volume into another container using the --volumes-from switch. You cannot attach or modify volumes while containers are running.

In fact even if you stop containers you cannot add volumes without deleting and recreating the container using the volumes-from switch. This seems very stringent but docker containers are meant to be stateless hence this should not be a problem if your containers are defined well.

Comment: To be clear, what you are implicitly saying is it cannot be something in a running volume, ie, you must commit first or it be in the image. (Wasn't talking about between the host, only between applications. If you edit to reflect that i will accept)

Comment: Yes for container to container shared volumes the volume definition must be part of the container image definition.